# React component doesnnt re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-redux

im passing values using react redux everything is passed but the component i want to render only renders 1 time and when i save my code in vscode (it renders again)the data renders on page like it should

```
return (
    <div className='fav-container' id='favorites'>

    {FavoritesData.data.length === 0 ? (
            <h5>You Don't Have Any Favorites Yet!</h5>
        ) : (
            <div className="favorites-grid">{FavoritesData.data.map((item) =>  <Favorite item={item} />)}</div>
        )}


    
      <button onClick={() => console.log(FavoritesData.data.length)}></button>
    </div>
);
```

on the log the data updates but the trenary function dont trigger same goes for useEffect

Comment: can you show the code in your useEffect aswell ?

Comment: You'll need to supply the code from the entire component.  This is a state management issue most likely. Or, as mentioned above, a simple useEffect solution.

Comment: the problem is i cant post all the state management here cuz of simplicity reason i would love to talk with you on discord if possible <3

Answer (score 0):

Are you overwriting data or just updating it? If you're just updating in-place, the reference won't change. I don't have quite enough information to make this diagnosis, but I'm suspecting that you're seeing the same behavior in React as you'd see here:

```js
// in the example below, the two variables are essentially storing the exact same array, not copies of the same array
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
// storing a reference to the myArr array
const myOtherArr = myArr;

myOtherArr.push(4);
console.log(myArr); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]

// in this example, the arrays are different
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
// store a copy of all the values from myArr in a new array literal
const myOtherArr = [...myArr];

myOtherArr.push(4);
console.log(myArr) // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

In React, which enforces a functional approach, you'd want to overwrite `FavoritesData.data` entirely, otherwise the reference won't actually change and React will think that it's looking at the exact same array. If you suspect that this is a misdiagnosis or if you still have questions, please post the code that updates `FavoritesData.data` and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in updating the values the problem its not looping through the components

I update it with redux, reducer:

```
        case 'ADD_FAVORITES':
            state.data.push(action.payload)
            return state 
            
        case  'DEL_FAVORITES':
        let favoritesArr = [ ...state.data ];
        state.data = favoritesArr.filter(fav => fav.cityName !== action.payload.cityName);  
        return state
        
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

The click `useEffect` in the other component

```
useEffect(() => {
       
           const fav = {
                cityName:CityData.EnglishName,
                TemperatureMetricValue:WeatherData.TemperatureMetricValue,
                TemperatureImperialValue: WeatherData.TemperatureImperialValue,
                WeatherText: WeatherData.WeatherText}
            
            const FavoritesPromise = async (favorites) => {


                return favorites;
            }              
       
         
         isClick ?  
             FavoritesPromise(fav)
            .then(data=>{

            dispatch(addFavorites(data))
            localStorage.setItem('location',JSON.stringify(FavoritesData.data))
             }) 
            .catch(err => console.log(err)) 

            :  FavoritesPromise(fav)
            .then(data=>{
                FavoritesData.data.map((item) => {
                    if(item.cityName == CityData.EnglishName){
                        dispatch(delFavorites(item))
                        localStorage.setItem('location',JSON.stringify(FavoritesData.data))


                    }

                })

             }) 
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    },[isClick])
```

Now when I try to return the value to the html it doesn't render it but when I log the values it seems like it is passing it.

```
 return (
    <div className='fav-container' id='favorites'>

    {FavoritesData.data.length === 0 ? (
            <h5>You Don't Have Any Favorites Yet!</h5>
        ) : (
            <div className="favorites-grid">{FavoritesData.data.map((item) =>  <Favorite item={item} />)}</div>
        )}
```

When I log the length it is changing, I tried the same logic with `useEffect` when the lengths changes and its not triggering as well.

```
      <button onClick={() => console.log(FavoritesData.data.length)}></button>
    </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: `state.data.push()` may be the problem because it won't actually update the reference, which means the component will never know to re-render.

Comment: how can it be? 
the array length is growing which means that the object is changing
If so what way can i update the data?

btw when i log the objectlength it is updated thats why idk why the useEffect or the map dont work

Comment: The js interpreter interprets arrays as references, not values. Essentially what that means is that all js remembers about the array when you store it in a variable is where the array is located in memory. Since that memory location doesn't change when you do an in-place operation, React has no way of actually knowing whether any values in the array or other properties of the array have changed, even if you can console.log to verify that those values have changed at runtime, because it's only able to see where the array lives in memory (otherwise known as a reference or pointer).

Comment: [This article](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) may help.